# Usage de "La madeleine de Proust"

Tags: expressions, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

L'expression ["la madeleine de Proust"](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/une-madeleine-de-proust) est une expression qui parle de quelque chose qui déclenche le mémoire (un déjà-vu). Peut-on employer l'expression couramment ?

Comment: Oui c'est assez courant, mais j'ai l'impression que c'est assez mal employé. Souvent juste pour dire qu'on aime particulièrement quelque chose, sans forcément avoir la notion de souvenirs enfouis qui remontent.

Comment: C'est très courant. C'est employé même par des gens qui n'ont pas lu  *À la recherche du temps perdu*. Tu pourrais lire le [début de du côté de chez Swann](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Du_c%C3%B4t%C3%A9_de_chez_Swann/Partie_1) qui commence par une phrase aussi très célèbre (« longtemps je me suis couché de bonne heure ») le passage sur la Madeleine commence par « Il y avait déjà bien des années que, de Combray... ».

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je devrais relativiser, donc, même si très courant ne veut pas dit universellement connu, et je ne parlais que pour la France, ce que je n'ai pas dit. Disons qu'un bachelier français (bachelier de section littéraire) connaît en général, c'est le passage de Proust le plus étudié au lycée. Cf mon commentaire sous la réponse de LPH.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais lu Proust et je connaissais l'expression, pour moi c'est une expression courante, souvent dans des discours politiques par exemple.

Comment: @Personne Thanks. Instead of correcting it I made it worse:-)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On s'aperçoit à partir d'un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+madeleine+de+Proust&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20madeleine%20de%20Proust%3B%2Cc0) que depuis 1940 la popularité de cette expression n'a pas cessé de grandir. Néanmoins, elle ne sera toujours pas connue de tout le monde. Je n'en suis aucunement conscient, comme je n'ai pas lu le livre de Proust dans lequel est narré cette anecdote à propos des madeleines et comme je n'ai jamais entendu personne y référer ; donc je suis dans le cas de nombreuses personnes qui confrontées à cette référence dans la conversation de quelqu'un, ne comprendraient pas.
 Il en va de même pour des quantités de références parce que évidemment on ne peut pas les avoir apprises toutes. Nous en sommes tous à ce points, sauf quelques spécialistes dans le domaine des études littéraires. C'est une des raisons pour lesquelles il ne faut pas trop s'en tenir à la popularité d'une anecdote ou d'une pensée pour s'en servir : comme dans ce cas-ci, il est suffisant que la référence soit tirée d'un auteur sérieux pour l'avancer et si l'interlocuteur n'est pas familier avec l'idée il suffit de quelques mots pour le renseigner. En fait, il n'y a même pas besoin que la référence proviennent de quelqu'un de grande renommée :  elle peut provenir simplement d'un ami et alors on peut toujours l'utiliser en l'expliquant rapidement ou encore elle peut provenir d'une culture étrangère et être quelque chose de très obscur ; cela se fait couramment.

Donc il me semble que rien ne peut retenir quelqu'un de référer à cet état de chose concernant la mémoire en utilisant cette expression.

Comment: Sans vouloir être catégorique (il faudrait pour cela une étude statistiques chiffrées) je pense que cette popularité croissante peut être due à la présence de Proust dans les programmes de français du lycée. Je ne sais pas depuis quand mais je peux dire que c'est postérieur aux années 70. Et un des textes les plus étudiés est probablement le début de du côté de chez Swann (« La Madeleine ». [Pour sourire](http://lechodelaboucle.fr/2015/02/18/la-madeleine-proust-enseignee-par-erreur-dans-un-lycee-du-haut-doubs/) (je ne sais pas si c'est vrai, ça parait gros !).

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous … pour le sourire … vrai ou faux, c’est très habilement rédigé, j’ai eu d’autant plus de plaisir à le lire que les récits des aventures du nombril du p’tit Marcel me sont systématiquement tombées des mains.

Answer (score 3):

La madeleine de Proust, dans le premier tome (Du côté de chez Swann) de "La Recherche", acronyme un peu snob pour ceux qui ont lu les sept tomes de "A la recherche du temps perdu", la madeleine donc, n'est pas exactement un déjà-vu, c'est un instant où le narrateur revit intégralement un moment du passé, dans cet exemple à l'occasion de l'ingestion de la poussière de madeleine trempée dans le thé.

Le déjà-vu possède une composante nauséeuse qui n'est pas présente chez Proust. La page qui décrit cette expérience de mémoire fait à juste titre partie du patrimoine français comme l'expression du génie de Marcel Proust qui parvient à formuler par quelques longues phrases parfaitement intelligibles l'expérience étrange et difficilement renouvelable du voyage dans le passé, non pas comme un souvenir lointain, mais comme une aventure vécue.

Comment: Petite correction sur une faute très courante: *acronyme* désigne une abréviation spécifique (composée de lettres ou syllabes initiales, mais prononcée comme un seu mot et non épelée lettre par lettre, comme p.ex. OTAN ou sida). "La recherche" n'est donc pas un acronyme.